# flask printing visitor ip to the console or saving as JSON file

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application, where I would like to get the visitors IP-address, and either print it to the console or save it into a JSON file.

The problem is that I get an unexpected indent error, whenever I try to do it.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    requester = request.remote_addr
    print(requester)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

i have tried making the requester object outside of my index function, however that causes another error as such:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

how can I fix this, so that I can get a global variable that holds the IP address of the user?

Comment: How do you make request object? Isn't you just import `request` from `flask`?

Comment: Yes i import it from as such 
from flask import request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nicer if you provided the exact "unexpected indent" error. As the error says, you probably have wrong indentation somewhere. Maybe mixing tabs and spaces?

Code example below works for me and prints the remote address. I'm using Python 3.6 and Flask 1.0.2.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    requester = request.remote_addr
    print(requester)
    return render_template('index.html')


app.run()
```

And yes, you can use `flask.request` only in part of code that is processing the request. Why would you need global variable to hold visitor IP? You can always pass the `requester` variable to some function.

One more thing: be careful when using `remote_addr` to fetch the visitor IP. This will work only if your clients are contacting your flask app directly. If your flask app is behind a web server or a load balancer (such as nginx, HAproxy or ELB), then you have to setup your web server to properly forward the visitor IP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have any source in regards to setup IP-forwarding with a server like NGinx?

Comment: something like this: https://calvin.me/forward-ip-addresses-when-using-nginx-proxy/